# Pull ad Earnings numbers from Youtube API

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-analytics-api

I'm trying to pull some earnings data from `youtubeAnalytics.reports.query`.

My google account is linked to a YouTube CMS, that manages 100+ channels, and I'm using that google account to authenticate my request.

So to make this super simple I'm gonna use one of Google's sample requests, namely this one:

> First one under `Earnings/Ads` in this link https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/sample-requests#content-owner-earnings-ads-reports
>
> Which will lead you more importantly to this filled out **[API EXPLORER](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtubeAnalytics/v1/youtubeAnalytics.reports.query?metrics=views%252Cearnings%252CadEarnings%252CgrossRevenue%252CplaybackBasedCpm%252CmonetizedPlaybacks%252Cimpressions%252CimpressionBasedCpm&filters=claimedStatus%253D%253Dclaimed&start-date=2015-09-01&end-date=2015-11-27&&ids=contentOwner%253D%253DCONTENT_OWNER_ID)**

inside you'll see `id` being `contentOwner==CONTENT_OWNER_ID` where `CONTENT_OWNER_ID` is explained in the description as:

> To request data for a YouTube CMS content owner, set the ids parameter value to contentOwner==OWNER_NAME, where OWNER_NAME is the CMS name of the content owner.

Which please correct me if I'm wrong, you're supposed to get from here:

[image: The HomePage from the CMS]

---

I've tried countless times with different variations and I haven't gotten it to succeed once. But following the sample request linked above I always get this:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "forbidden",
    "message": "Forbidden"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Forbidden"
 }
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using your content owner name, you can use your content owner ID. You can find your content owner ID from the following url;

https://developers.google.com/youtube/partner/docs/v1/contentOwners/list#try-it

Most of the requests on Analytics and Reporting API are using Content Owner ID, instead of Content Owner Name.

I hope it helps.

Comment: duuuude you were sooo clooose. But it really doesn't matter cuz thanks to you now I know why the heck it wasn't working!!!

I'll edit your answer and select it.

Comment: I'm glad that you found the way of solving your issue :)